# How to generate encoded polylines from shapefile/ kml?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis, polyline

I need to convert a shapefile/ kml to encoded polyline format for a certain project. Does anyone know of a simple conversion tool or code that achieves the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll first want to convert your KML/SHP to a list of lat/long pairs. For KML, you can simply open the KML file in an editor to get the lat/long pairs. For SHP, you can first use [`shp2kml`](http://www.zonums.com/shp2kml.html) to convert to KML.

Then, use the [`encoding`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#encoding) library in the Maps API, or you can write your own encoder using [the algorithm](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm.html).

Comment: Actually i want a code to perform the encoding because the number of polylines that i want to encode is huge...

Answer (score -1):

Your term shapefile/kml is confusing.  If you want to convert from an ESRI shapefile to a kml file, the utility ogr2ogr works like this:

```
 ogr2ogr -f "KML" outputfile.kml sourcefile.shp.
```

For downloads, ogr2ogr is part of the GDAL distribution: http://www.gdal.org/

Comment: 'shapefile/kml' means "shapefile, or kml". The OP most likely has both formats available, or can easily convert from one to the other. So they listed what they had available in case one or the other is possible/more easily achived. Hopefully this clears up your confusion.