# Bulk Shapefile to KML conversion

Tags: google-maps, kml, shapefile, esri

Are there any applications or utilities that can convert a large number of shapefiles to kml? Or has anyone has success parsing these types of files into KML?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate encoded polylines from shapefile/ kml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242988/how-to-generate-encoded-polylines-from-shapefile-kml).  I usually use `ogr2ogr`

Comment: Ill give GDAL a shot.

Comment: Shp2kml2 looks like it does not work at all just get an error message every time I try and convert

Comment: Haven't used Shp2kml2 myself, I use something like this from the other answer there: `ogr2ogr -f "KML" outputfile.kml sourcefile.shp`

Comment: Okay thanks. Ill try and configure that

Comment: Finally got ogr2ogr installed, looks like the conversion works!

Comment: @geocodezip was browsing unanswered posts and found this. Your comment regarding `ogr2ogr` is essentially the answer. Would you like to post it?